# What are Cyanogenmod's profiles good for?

Tags: cyanogenmod, profiles

I just installed ICS CM9 on my Galaxy Note and I am puzzled by the "Profiles" setting. It seems to allow me to set-up different profiles (home, work, etc) and associate settings with them, eg enable Bluetooth and disable GPS at home.

But I didn't see any way to automatically change profiles according to, for example, presence of a given WIFI network. So, my question is: *what are those profiles for?* Should I manually switch profile from work to home when I come back home? This make no sense!

I searched but didn't find anything relevant, maybe because "profile" is a very generic noun.

Comment: Edited the OP to reflect that... Yes, they're CM7+ specific and rather useful (imho), have [NFC-trigger-support](https://plus.google.com/100275307499530023476/posts/Xi8gSveVKFq), CM's [forum](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/38014-what-are-profiles/) has more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to manually switch to Home profile when you come back home. Its what you can find in classic mobile phones.

If you want to automate it, there're plenty of apps for that: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)+[Profile4Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.martinutils.profiletasker) (paid), [AutomateIt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage) (free), [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) (free), [Locale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twofortyfouram.locale)+[Profile4Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.martinutils.profiletasker) (paid)

Comment: currently researching how to set them with intents not using Profile4tasker (seems with NFC there are random like identifiers involved as "salt" to prevent malicious switching)

Comment: Llama is great but it doesn't automate the types of profiles mentioned here. It has its own profiles.

Answer (score 3):

As listed in http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/EndUser.Profiles (already mentioned), the only support for automatic switching provided out-of-the-box with CyanogenMod is via Clock (Alarms) application. Each alarm can also trigger a profile change.

For WiFi-, location-, etc- based changes you'd have to use other options. Some of them are also listed on the above wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same answers on the same question. 
This post from the CM team had all the answers I was looking for:

http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/EndUser.Profiles

Comment: Broken link. Please update it.

Answer (score 1):

When updating to 10.1.3, the Google Maps icon becomes visible at the bottom of the profile being edited. There, you can select triggers based on joining a certain Wi-Fi network, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with no additional applications, they can switch automatically say on a particular WiFi connection/disconnection, but discovering that feature is hiding in a most non-intuitive location.

At the bottom of the profile edit page hiding near your home button you will see a "Google map" placemarker icon.

Click on it.  That takes you to the trigger page, where you can set the profile to automagically activate/deactivate on WiFi or Bluetooth and I think NFC though I've never used that particular tech "feature" looking for a useful purpose.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't added an application which can do that? I am running CM 10.1 and I do not have this option in the the Profile edit Setting page. (e.g. System Settings-->Profile-->Work)

Answer (score 0):

the Google maps icon leading to a triggers page is definitely present in CM11 (KitKat).

This allows you to set certain features based on events such as WiFi networks / NFC tags, etc.

I can't recall having seen it before, but as stated - it isn' the most intuitive of locations, I only stumbled on it because I thought my phone was changing* profiles due to some sort of GeoTagging.

*the profile change was actually caused by the clock (alarm), which can be used as a timed profile change every morning (e.g. force your phone into default with your morning alarm clock).... bizarrely, these timed changes are NOT visible/accessible from the profiles config page.